# How to remove "Text selection" context action bar for EditText but keep text selection functionality

Tags: android

I want to create custom interface for basic copy, cut, paste and format operations on EditText. But when I start to select text, text selection context bar shows up at the top. And I'm unable to figure out how to **remove CAB** and still **keep ability to select text**.

Using `setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback` with overwritten `ActionMode.Callback` removes context bar, but it also removes ability to select text.

Answer (score 1):

You can completely remove ActionBarContextView.

So, use this code:

```
    tv.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new ActionMode.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            removeActionBar(getWindow().getDecorView());
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode actionMode, MenuItem menuItem) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode actionMode) {

        }
    });

    private void removeActionBar(View v) {
            ViewGroup viewgroup = (ViewGroup) v;

            for (int i = 0; i < viewgroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    View v1=viewgroup.getChildAt(i);
                    if ( v1 instanceof ViewGroup )
                            removeActionBar(v1);
                    if ( v1 instanceof ActionBarContextView ) {
                            viewgroup.removeView(v1);
                    }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Please give some context to your answer and don't just post code.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by changing style of `*actionMode*` items in styles.xml.

Idea is to make action mode action bar overlay window, be 1px in height, transparent and with default drawables set to blank.

**styles.xml** style

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>

    <!--how to hide action mode-->
    <item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeStyle">@style/ActionModeStyleBlank</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeCopyDrawable">@drawable/blank</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeCloseDrawable">@drawable/blank</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeCutDrawable">@drawable/blank</item>
    <item name="android:actionModePasteDrawable">@drawable/blank</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeSelectAllDrawable">@drawable/blank</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeSplitBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>

<!--size should be 1px otherwise full size action bar is shown -->
<style name="ActionModeStyleBlank">
    <item name="android:actionBarSize">1px</item>
    <item name="android:height">1px</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

**blank.xml** drawable

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
<size android:height="0px" android:width="0px"></size>
</shape>
```

Comment: I tested this solution only on Android 5.1.1 at this time

Comment: This solution doesn't work on android 6, is there any alternative?